# spark_write_rds() function fails to load data on HDFS

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs, sparklyr

I am using the function spark_write_rds() which is implemented in sparklyr 1.6.0, to load the data on HDFS as follows:

```
spark_write_rds(
      sdf,
      dest_uri = "hdfs://<namenode>:8020/sdf-{partitionId}.rds"
    )
```

and costantly getting the following error:

> Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the "clustername"FileSystem FileSystem implementation

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

- I replaced the clustername in error message.

Comment: Same issue. No solution. Will be watching this space. "Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DBFS FileSystem implementation"